# how to export nodecore text to markdown *not* as header (#, ##)

Tags: documentation, markdown, mind-mapping, freemind

I exported the tutorial to markdown, I noticed that large chunks of text such as this one were exported to standard markdown text:

[image]

[image]

However when I create my own nodecore text it is always exported to markdown titles, how can I have the text exported to standard text in markdown?

UPDATE 05/04/2018: Please note I have tagged the question as freemind because there is no freeplane tag and this is the closest tag.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://sourceforge.net/p/freemind/discussion/22102/thread/132eeb5c/

Comment: Or this? https://sourceforge.net/p/freemind/discussion/22101/thread/4fdddf74/

Comment: sorry it looks like they are talking of freemind and export to plaintext, I read it but not sure if it helps me , i'm able to export it to markdown only it's only headers and it's freeplane.

Comment: you literally tagged [tag:freemind] in the question -_-

Comment: yeah sorry for that there was no `freeplane` tag :/ and as I thougt freeplane is a fork of freemind that was the closest one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, I had to change the font size to 7 or less in freeplane.

Answer (score 1):

In markdown, you can write hash title `##` as-is by escaping it with backslash `\##`.

But for such case, I recommend to use code block as it will also preserve new lines as well. Code block can be written by writing three backticks ```` ``` ```` around the code.

[image: Preview Markdown in VSCode]